# Scroll in TableLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I wanted to put a vertical ScrollView I have inserted the table that I have tried in various ways but it gives me error, I hope you can help me, greetings.
my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutTabla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerDatos"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </TableRow>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnVer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnVer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Ver datos de" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerDatos"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVer"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LayoutTabla"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinnerDatos"
        android:onClick="verTablaDatos"
        android:text="Ver" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to put the scroll to `<TableLayout>`
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encasing the TableLayout in:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutTabla"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerDatos"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp" >
```

Comment: now the problem is that the scroll not only lowers down completely until the TableLayout reaches the top of the screen, you know? , Why is this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you mean that you can't see the entire layout?

Comment: My problem is I have a table layout which the'm getting data dynamically ie not have a fixed size. that failure is not scrolling down completely. not see the entire table.